# World Map Viewer with LibGDX

Tags: java, game, libgdx

I am working on a game where the player can walk around a world comprised out of a grid of tiles.  The `World` object contains a `HashMap` of `Region` objects which each has a `HashMap` of `Tile` objects.

For the libGDX side of things, the `Game` object creates the different `Screen`s of the game, and switching between `Screen`s is handled by calls to the `Stage` of the `Game` object.

The following code is the code for the world map for the game.  When the user presses the Map button, its swipe recognizer is disabled and it tells the `Game` to tell its `Stage` to load the `MapScreen`.

There is a lot of coupling going on with each `Screen` and the `Game`.  I know that this is a problem, but I don't know the best way to go about fixing it.  I am happy to hear any and all criticism about the code.

```
public class MapScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

    //used to center the content of the screen
    private final int screenX = 15;
    private final int screenY = 120;

    private final int tileSize = 15;
    private final int tileSpacing = 3;
    private final ShapeRenderer shape = new ShapeRenderer();

    private final Skin skin;
    private Table table;

    private final SCGame game;
    private final World gameWorld;

    public MapScreen(SCGame game, World gameWorld) {
        this.skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
        this.game = game;
        this.gameWorld = gameWorld;
        this.enableCameraPanning();
        this.createButtons();
    }

    private void enableCameraPanning() {
        this.game.cameraPanner.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void createButtons() {
        TextButton exitButton = new TextButton("Exit", skin);
        exitButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                MapScreen.this.clickedMapButton();
            }
        });

        this.table = new Table();
        table.setPosition((float)(-SCGame.STAGE_WIDTH/2.3), (float)(-SCGame.STAGE_HEIGHT/2.2));
        table.setFillParent(true);
        table.add(exitButton).right().bottom();
        this.game.stage.addActor(this.table);
    }

    private void clickedMapButton() {
        this.table.remove();
        this.game.camera.setToOrtho(false, SCGame.STAGE_WIDTH, SCGame.STAGE_HEIGHT);
        this.game.cameraPanner.setEnabled(false);
        this.game.closeMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void render (float delta) {  
        draw();
    }

    private void draw() {

        //region tiles
        shape.setProjectionMatrix(this.game.camera.combined); //for the screen resize
        shape.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        if (this.gameWorld != null) {
            for (Region region : this.gameWorld.allRegionsForMap()) {
                for (Tile tile : region.allTiles()) {
                    shape.setColor(this.colorForType(tile.type));
                    int totalTileSize = tileSize + tileSpacing;
                    int xDistance = tile.position().x() + region.worldPosition().x() * this.gameWorld.numTilesPerRow;
                    int yDistance = tile.position().y() + region.worldPosition().y() * this.gameWorld.numRows;
                    shape.rect(xDistance * totalTileSize + this.screenX, 
                               yDistance * totalTileSize + this.screenY,  
                               tileSize, tileSize );

                }
            }
        }

        //player position
        shape.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        int totalTileSize = tileSize + tileSpacing;
        int xDistance = this.gameWorld.playerPosition().x() + this.gameWorld.currentRegion().worldPosition().x() * this.gameWorld.numTilesPerRow;
        int yDistance = this.gameWorld.playerPosition().y() + this.gameWorld.currentRegion().worldPosition().y() * this.gameWorld.numRows;
        shape.rect(xDistance * totalTileSize + this.screenX, 
                   yDistance * totalTileSize + this.screenY, 
                   tileSize, tileSize);

        shape.end();
    }

    private Color colorForType(TileType type) {
        switch(type) {
            case GRASS:
                return Color.GREEN;
            case FOREST:
                return Color.OLIVE;
            case MOUNTAIN:
                return Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
            case SWAMP:
                return Color.CYAN;
            case DESERT:
                return Color.YELLOW;
            case WASTES:
                return Color.ORANGE;
            default:
                return Color.BLACK;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: map view]

Comment: "tells the Game to tell its Stage to load the MapScreen." - technically, the game is told to load the MapScreen, it doesn't go through the Stage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like these variables might be better off as constants:

```
    private final int screenX = 15;
    private final int screenY = 120;
    private final int tileSize = 15;
    private final int tileSpacing = 3;
```

Adding `static` to them and renaming them to use `CONSTANT_CASE` will take care of that.

---

```
private final ShapeRenderer shape = new ShapeRenderer();
```

**Possible Memory Leak!** You are never calling `shape.dispose();` I would recommend creating this `ShapeRenderer` in your `SCGame` class and pass it to the screen(s). Then your `SCGame` can take care of properly disposing it as well.

Alternatively, you need to take care of [disposing your screens yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392250/proper-way-to-dispose-screens-in-libgdx) and put the disposing on it in a `@Override public void dispose()` method.

---

I would make your `Table` final and create it inside the constructor instead of putting it inside a `createButtons` method. You're only calling `createButtons` from the constructor currently.

---

You are right about the coupling with `SCGame`. That's not ideal.

What I am trying to do in LibGDX projects is to put the things required by other screens into some kind of a home-made `GameContext` class. Sort of like this:

```
public class GameContext {

    private final Camera camera;
    private final Skin skin;
    private final Stage stage;

    public GameContext(Camera camera, Skin skin, Stage stage) {
        this.camera = camera;
        this.skin = skin;
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }

    public Camera getCamera() {
        return camera;
    }

    public Skin getSkin() {
        return skin;
    }

}
```

Passing an instance of `GameContext` around to your screens will keep them independent on your `SCGame` class. Of course you can also add other resources to this class that you want your screens to have.

Another approach is also to *extract an interface* that contains the methods you want to have access to, such as:

```
public interface GameInterface {
    void backToMainMenu();
}
```

Then you could have your `SCGame` implement this interface, and pass around *the interface* to your classes.

```
public MapScreen(GameInterface game, World gameWorld) {
    this.game = game;
    ...
}
```

---

```
table.setPosition((float)(-SCGame.STAGE_WIDTH/2.3), (float)(-SCGame.STAGE_HEIGHT/2.2));
```

This is some strange code that you really shouldn't need to have. Your table *should* position itself correctly to stretch across the screen without this code.

After a bit of testing, I found that the current code centers the button, not puts it into the bottom-right corner. The correct way is either:

```
this.table = new Table();
this.table.setFillParent(true);
this.table.add(mapButton).expand().right().bottom();
this.game.stage.addActor(this.table);
```

Or:

```
this.table = new Table();
this.table.setFillParent(true);
this.table.right().bottom();
this.table.add(mapButton);
this.game.stage.addActor(this.table);
```

Then you probably will want some margin between the button and the edge of the screen as well, which you can do by adding `.pad(10)` at the end of the `table.add(mapButton)` line.

---

```
@Override
public void render (float delta) {  
    draw();
}
```

Well, that was a useful method!

Please do us a favor and move all your `draw()` code to this `render()` method instead. There's really no need for both.

---

```
private Color colorForType(TileType type) {
    switch(type) {
        case GRASS:
            return Color.GREEN;
```

So you are associating each of your `TileType` members with a color?

Use enum methods, my friend!

```
public enum TileType {
    GRASS(Color.GREEN),
    FOREST(Color.OLIVE),
    ...;

    private final Color color;

    private TileType(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }
}
```

Then instead of `colorForType(tileType)` you can call `tileType.getColor()` (unless `tileType` is null of course, but I hope you are avoiding that.